# Social Commeting system on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a serviss or plugin (better service), that can use it in this way:

First, if a am guest, then i can use twiter, facebook, etc, commenting, but if i log in on site with local user, then i have only post comment with my user. (all comments need one system, not spliting on local and service)

Also in plugin need existing username protection.

I tray this: intensedebate.com but dont have local user implations on plugin.

Also in servise or system need comments integration in exsisting wordpress system.

One word say: defolt wordpress commenting features with soc commenting system.

Better i need use some of commenting servisies, becouse i also use phpbbwp bridge plugin, that make wordpresss users intro phpbb3 and reverse.

Is there any good solution, for my advanced system?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options - use a plugin or implement Facebook/Twitter/etc auth manually. If you want the easy way - try one of these plugins:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rpx/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social/

They both allow users to register/login via social network accounts as well as some more handy features. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

These two are the best, and fulfill your requirements:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/intensedebate/
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/disqus-comment-system/